# SQL if update() statement for a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want my trigger to only execute on a update if the old value is not equal to the new value. If the value remains the same, i do not want me if block to execute.

```
if UPDATE(interview)
    BEGIN 
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = 'SM_PRFL',
    @recipients = 'email',

    @subject = 'this is a test' ,
    @body = 'message'
            END
```

Comment: Don't forget my upvote, and most importantly post something in a comment to my answer to explain whether you needed to change anything so that people who come here in the future can reference the solution and learn what you learned from it! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following link, look for "Using the inserted and deleted Tables in INSTEAD OF Triggers" : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300(SQL.90).aspx

That should allow you to perform your tests and perform an action as required.  For example you could...

```
If ( Update(interview))
BEGIN
    -- If column esb has been changed from its previous value
    IF ((SELECT esb FROM INSERTED) <> select esb FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = 'SM_PRFL',
    @recipients = 'email',

    @subject = 'this is a test' ,
    @body = 'message'
    END
END
```